# isPasswordValid does not work with sha256

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I'm implementierung a ui for an existing oracle db with a users table and passwords stored as sha256 hashes. But the authenticator shows that the password is wrong.

Config:

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User:
      algorithm: sha256
```

Authenticator-Function:

```
public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
{
    return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']); // -> False
    return hash_equals(hash('sha256', $credentials['password']), $user->getPassword()); // -> True
}
```

As described if i manually check the password with hash_equals it works.
Can someone help? Might be a misconfiguration i think.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46877700/symfony-security-password-encoder-ispasswordvalid-is-returning-empty) can help?

Comment: Hi Magnus, it didn't help, but the answer from Alex below was the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sha256` is not a valid value for this YAML setting. Symfony doesn't (natively) support straight hashes like this because they're not considered strong enough for passwords.

If you really want to use SHA256 (you shouldn't) you can [create your own encoder](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/named_encoders.html).

Comment: Hi Alex, since i have to work with the existing database, i'll write my own encoder. Thanks for that.